# Save SharePoint list data from root site to subsite list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

Is it possible to save a newly created items from list one from the root site to the same list in the other sub-site?

Currently, we are implementing country specific site and we have a global site where the global news and announcement will be published then it will also be available to the country sites

```
Global Site
 ----> News List
     News 1

/en-US
 ----> News List
     News 1 from the root site
     News en-US
/en-PH
 ---> News List
    News PH
    News 1 from the root site
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SharePoint workflow, we can use "Call HTTP web service" action to call the REST to post new item into another site. The following articles for your reference:

**Working with Web Services in SharePoint 2013 Workflows using SharePoint Designer 2013**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx

**Calling the SharePoint 2013 Rest API from a SharePoint Designer Workflow**

https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Or we can also use Remote Event Receiver with Client Object Model to achieve it.
On-Premise, we can also use Event Receiver.